# How to iterate through a JSON list to find just the URLs of my website?

Tags: python, json, wordpress

I'm pulling the JSON data from my website and I want to append the URLs (permalinks) of all my posts to a list.  I'm trying to iterate through the JSON file using the code below but I get a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when I try the for loop.  Can anyone help?

```py
import urllib.request
import json

get_data_url = "http://www.financialgenomeproject.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
json_get_data_url = urllib.request.urlopen(get_data_url)
resp = json.load(json_get_data_url)

url_list = []
for i in resp('content'):
    if i('rendered') == 'href=':
        url_list.append(['href='])

print(url_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need the rendererd key because protected is of type bool.Then you can use `str.index` 
to select which part of the string to select.

```
import urllib.request
import json

get_data_url = "http://www.financialgenomeproject.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
json_get_data_url = urllib.request.urlopen(get_data_url)
resp = json.load(json_get_data_url)
```

---

```
url_list=[]
for my_dict in resp:
    for key in my_dict['content']:
        if key == 'rendered':
            my_dict2=my_dict['content'][key]
            idi=my_dict2.index('href="http')+len('href="')
            idf=my_dict2.index('/"')+1
            url=my_dict2[idi:idf]
            url_list.append(url)
            print(url)
```

---

**Output:**

```
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2019/05/31/chapter-25-home-not-asset/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2017/02/26/chapter-3-benjamin-franklin-first-tax-planner/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/table-of-contents/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2018/11/30/chapter-22-land-ownership/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/about/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2017/08/23/financial-genome-project-chapter-7/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2017/09/24/financial-genome-project-chapter-8/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2017/09/24/financial-genome-project-chapter-8/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2016/12/09/financial-genome-project-1/
http://financialgenomeproject.net/2018/04/09/chapter-15-do-you-need-a-budget/
```

## time it takes to get the url

```
%%timeit
url_list=[]
for my_dict in resp:
    for key in my_dict['content']:
        if key == 'rendered':
            my_dict2=my_dict['content'][key]
            idi=my_dict2.index('href="http')+len('href="')
            idf=my_dict2.index('/"')+1
            url=my_dict2[idi:idf]
            url_list.append(url)
#27.4 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

now with **print**

```
%%timeit
url_list=[]
for my_dict in resp:
    for key in my_dict['content']:
        if key == 'rendered':
            my_dict2=my_dict['content'][key]
            idi=my_dict2.index('href="http')+len('href="')
            idf=my_dict2.index('/"')+1
            url=my_dict2[idi:idf]
            url_list.append(url)
            print(url)
#1.42 ms ± 60.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

as you can see if `print(url)` is included, the time increases considerably so it would be advisable to comment on this line if you do not need to view it immediately

Comment: This is so perfect!  Thank you so much.  This code is a little above my weight class, so I'm going to sit down and really learn it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do not worry. I have included the timing of this task, with and without `print`. If you want you can browse it :)

Answer (score 0):

The json you loaded is a list which you stored in the variable `resp`. You cannot call a list, which is what `resp('content')` is trying to do. Instead, just iterate over the list:

```py
for i in resp:
    if i['rendered'] == 'href=':
        url_list.append(['href='])
```

Not that I also substituted the erroneous `i('rendered')` with `i['rendered']`.

The code in the loop does not make much sense, to be honest. You should read more about how Python works.